# Probabilities with normal distributions

Tags: statistics

Determine the probabilities for the following normal distributions. 
a. mean=12 standard dev= 4   P(8 -< x -<16)
b. mean= 0 standard dev: 1   P(-1.96 -< x -< 1.96) 
c. mean=0 standard dev: 1    P(-2.575 -

I tried doing it the way I learned it, but it is coming out to 0 every time which makes no sense. I'm hoping someone good at Statistics can help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For $\mu = 12,\sigma = 4$ and $\mathbb{P}(8\leq x \leq 16)$

$$Z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$

First calculate

$$\frac{8-12}{4} = -1 = Z_{\mbox{calc}}$$

Then reading it off a table this gives

$$\mathbb{P}(x\leq 8) = \mathbb{P}(Z\leq -1) \approx 0.1587$$

Repeating this for 16, we have

$$\frac{16-12}{4} = 1 = Z_{\mbox{calc}}$$

again, reading this off a table we get

$$\mathbb{P}(x\leq 16) = \mathbb{P}(Z \leq 1) \approx 0.8413$$

So $$\mathbb{P}(8\leq x \leq 16) = \mathbb{P}(x\leq 16) - \mathbb{P}(x\leq 8) \approx 0.6826$$

Note that this heavily depends on the tables you are using, different tables may give you different areas under the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question (c) is partially missing, but judging by (a) and (b) and what I can see of (c), it looks like the question is asking you about some fairly standard points on the normal distribution:

(a) As pointed out by @JessicaK, this is asking you for the probability that a normal variable falls within 1 stdev of its mean, which is 68%

(b) Same type of problem, but now it wants probability that its within 1.96 stdev of the mean. This is an important cutoff, as it is the cutoff for 95% confidence intervals. The probability here is 95%.

(c) This is cut off, but a random variable is within 2.575 stdev of its mean 99% of the time.

Each of these cutoffs is pretty standard, and forms the triad of 68\95\99 percent cutoffs that you will often see with confidence intervals and two-sided hypothesis tests.

The best way to evaluate these is using Excel or a numerical package with a stats package that has the normal distribution. A table is OK if it goes to the third decimal point, either way should get you essentially the same answer.

If you are using tables, the trick is to first STANDARDIZE your variable to a Normal(0,1) random variable. You do this by subtracting the mean from both sides of the desired interval and then dividing by the standard deviation. Again, Jessica showed how to do this for problem (a).